# Log analysis tool, shows a timeline of event frequency

Tags: gratis, linux, log-analysis

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
06:24:35,524 WARN [ajp-bio-8009-exec-57804][c3p0] Temperature high
16:07:40,457 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-156][c3p0] Brain not found 
17:07:47,789 INFO [ajp-bio-8009-exec-57804][c3p0] Received salutation
17:07:47,885 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-156][c3p0] Brain not found 
17:07:50,875 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-156][c3p0] Brain not found 
17:08:02,746 ERROR [ajp-bio-8009-exec-156][c3p0] Brain not found 
20:27:51,179 WARN [ajp-bio-8009-exec-57804][c3p0] Temperature high
```

I want a tool to generate a graph showing the most frequent events, and their volume across time. That would make it easier to spot the peaks, and guess the causality between events.

The output could look like [image] (one small bar for each event occurrence or be more curve-like. Ideally it would allow switching between the two, as the first is better for small volumes and the second better for high volumes.

The graph should also show dates (if a GUI, on user action it could reveal the timestamp of each event) and the log message for each line/curve.

Bonus (optional):

- Allows me to select what log messages I want to show (I often want to ignore some trivial messages that come often).
- Correlates events (for instance if two messages always appear in pair, show the pair as a single message).

Comment: Can I suggest taking a look at https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-analysis-in-python-an-introduction-70d5a5b1d52a and also at http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

Use sed to insert a `;` character just after the timestamp:

```
sed -i -e "s/^\(..\):\(..\):\(..\),\(...\) /\1:\2:\3,\4;/" $FILE
```

Open the CSV file with LibreOffice Calc, make sure to choose the right delimiter so that your timestamp is in the first column.

Example:

[image]

Convert the timestamp column from text type to date type, as described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370227/2305

Save as a spreadsheet.

Create a new column between the timestamp and the message, and type this formula in the topmost cell:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2, "*Temperature high*"), "1", IF(COUNTIF(A2, "*Brain not found*"), "2", 0)
```

You get the idea, replace the default value `0` by as many `IF`s as you need. This is quite lousy, inspired from [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14658/lookup-matching-regular-expression-in-calc/), but I haven't been able to make a wildcard VLOOKUP to catch values that often contain random identifiers.

Copy this formula to all cells below.

Select the timestamp and code columns, and press `Insert chart`.

Select `XY (Scatter)`

Uncheck `Display legend`, click `Finish`

Click on the numbers of the vertical axis, right-click and select `Format axis`, set the intervals to `1`.

Click on the points, right-click and select `Format data series` then on the `Line` tab reduce the width and increase the height.

This gives a chart like this:

[image]

Add a legend. Any tip on improving the formula part so that the legend gets used for parsing would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Mawg: It is all manual steps, with the spreadsheet formula being especially tedious to type. I hope some software will appear that does all of this automatically :-)

Comment: Ok, then leave it open. I suspect that I might one day want to follow those manual steps ;-)